# LaTeX table - extra alignment tab?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm new to LaTeX and trying to make a truth table, but it won't compile. When I try to run the code, it says "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr." Here is my code:

```
\item (Textbook 1.1/38, 4 points) $((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r)\rightarrow s$
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
$p$ & $q$ & $r$ & $s$ & $p\rightarrow q$ & $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow$ r & $((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r)\rightarrow s$ \\ 
\hline
T & T & T & T & T & T & T \\
T & T & T & F & T & T & F \\
T & T & F & T & T & F & T \\
T & F & T & T & F & T & T \\
T & F & T & F & F & T & F \\
T & F & F & T & F & T & T \\
T & F & F & F & F & T & F \\
F & T & T & T & T & T & T \\
F & T & T & F & T & T & F \\
F & T & F & T & T & F & T \\
F & T & F & F & T & F & T \\
F & F & T & T & T & T & T \\
F & F & T & F & T & T & F \\
F & F & F & T & T & F & T \\
F & F & F & F & T & F & T \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Note that StackExchange now has a [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) site. That's the best place to post LaTeX-only questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easily, you declared **six** columns: there are six `c` in the line

```latex
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
```

Then, every line of your table has **seven** cells instead:

```latex
...
T & T & T & T & T & T & T \\
...
```

So, you should solve by changing

```latex
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
```

to

```latex
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
```

or

```latex
\begin{tabular}{c*{6}{|c}}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is remove the `\\` at the end of the last line of the truth table. I would also suggest trying out Overleaf it allows you to see your code in real time and gives an easier debugging experience.

Comment: are you sure?? :) @nikosm

Comment: @nikosm Welcome to [so]! If your answer were correct, then it means the question should probably be closed as *off-topic: typographical error.* Adding more details to your answer might have saved it from downvotes, but would not have saved the whole question from getting closed/deleted.